# как выбить все окна чата при логауте из одного окна

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

Здравствуйте. Я по видеоурокам пытаюсь написать чат на socket.io. Мне нужно делать дисконект всем окнам одного пользователя, если он нажал логаут в одном окне. Но уроки сильно устарели и все что там показано, теперь не работает.

Вот код который у меня уже есть :

```
    var ip = 'localhost:*';
    io.set('origins', ip);

    io.use(function (socket, next) {
        socket.request.cookie = cookie.parse(socket.request.headers.cookie);
        var sid = cookieParser.signedCookie(socket.request.cookie['sid'], config.get('session:secret'));

        sessionStore.get(sid, function (err, session) {
            if (err) return next(err);

            if (!session) {
                return next(new HttpError(401, 'No session'));
            }

            socket.session = session;

            if (!session.user)  return next(HttpError(401, "anonimus session"));

            User.findById(session.user, function (err, user) {
                if (err)  return next(err);

                if (!user)  return next(new HttpError(401, "user not found in bd"))

                socket.user = user;
                next();
            })
        });
    });


    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        var username = socket.user.username;
        socket.emit('message', username + ' зашел');

        socket.on('message', function (text, callback) {
            socket.broadcast.emit('message', text);
            callback("ok")
        });
    });
};
```

теперь мне нужно при логауте перебрать все сокеты с таким же именем и дисконектить их.

Вот мой логаут метод:

```
exports.post = function (req, res,next) {

    var sid = req.session.id;
    var io = req.app.get('io');

    req.session.destroy(function (err) {
        io.sockets._events.sessreload(sid);   //  вызывает метод сокета
        if(err) return next(err);
        res.redirect('/');
    });
};
```

и вызывает он такой метод сокета:

```
io.on("sessreload",function(sid){
        // как перебрать подключенные сокеты ?
    });
```

Как я могу перебрать подключенные сокеты, чтобы я мог их отключать по свойству user?